# Why can't I get any dragon skin drops from Anacondaur?

Tags: final-fantasy-8

I've been trying for more than a few *hours* to fight Anacondaur and Grendels to get some Dragon Skins to upgrade weapons. I've fought probably 30-40 total battles, with about half as Anacondaur. It's bad enough that I've accidentally leveled to a party average of ~36, and I've still never gotten a Dragon Skin drop.

According to the [guides](http://guides.gamercorner.net/ffviii/items/dragon-skin), Anacondaur should drop Dragon Skins nearly every battle, especially with my current level.

What gives? I just want to upgrade some items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dragon Skins can only be gotten as an end-of-battle item drop. Not only can you not mug it, but if you do attempt to mug, you'll always get nothing at the end of the battle.

I knew that the item couldn't be mugged, but I didn't know that the item would never be dropped if mug was used. Turn off mug.